# Derivative of a Lyapunov function for a slowly time-varying system

Tags: partial-derivative, dynamical-systems, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following slowly time-varying system
$$\epsilon\dot{z}(t)=A(x(t))z(t),$$
$$\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t)).$$
Under some stability assumptions, it is proven that there exist a Lyapunov function for the system of the form
$$W(x,z)=z^\top P(x)z,$$
with $P(x)$ being a positive-definite symmetric matrix satisfying the equality
$$P(x)A(x)+A^\top(x)P(x) = -I.$$
In particular, the explicit form of $P(x)$ is given by
$$P(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{A^\top(x)\sigma}e^{A(x)\sigma}d\sigma.$$
At this point, it is given that the derivative of $W(x,z)$ along the trajectories of the system is:
$$\dot{W}=-\frac{1}{\epsilon}z^\top z+z^\top\dot{P}(x)z.$$

However, I don't understand exactly how to retrieve this expression since I go about it as:
$$\dot{W} = \frac{\partial W}{\partial x}\dot{x} + \frac{\partial W}{\partial z}\dot{z},$$
but then I don't know how to compute $\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial W}{\partial z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can differentiate $\dot W$ directly without the chain rule. I'll omit all $t$ dependencies. As $W=z^TPz$ the derivative is obtained from the product rule
$$
\dot W=\dot z^TPz+z^T\dot Pz+z^TP\dot z.
$$
The second term is present in the final expression, so we combine the first and the last ones and replace $\dot z=\frac{1}{\epsilon}Az$
$$
\dot z^TPz+z^TP\dot z=z^T\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}A^TP+P\frac{1}{\epsilon}A\right]z=\frac{1}{\epsilon}z^T[\underbrace{A^TP+PA}_{=-I}]z=-\frac{1}{\epsilon}z^Tz.
$$

Comment: Yeah I know, that is also how I tackled the problem. However, I am particularly interested in knowing how to compute $\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial W}{\partial z}$.

Comment: @ofir_13 $\frac{\partial W}{\partial z}=2z^TP$, i.e. $\frac{\partial W}{\partial z}\dot z$ are exactly the first and the last terms combined together in my answer. The expression for the derivative w.r.t. $x$ is messier (involving the derivative of a matrix w.r.t. a vector) $$\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{i,j}z_i z_j P_{ij}(x)=\sum_{i,j}z_i z_j\frac{\partial P_{ij}(x)}{\partial x}.$$ Thus $$\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}\dot x=\sum_{i,j}z_i z_j\underbrace{\frac{\partial P_{ij}(x)}{\partial x}\dot x}_{=\dot P_{ij}}=z^T\dot Pz.$$

Comment: The partial derivative $\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}$ could also be done by using vectorization of $P(x)$ and multiply it with $z$ using the Kronecker product, but should result into the same expression. Solving for $P(x)$ given $A(x)$ can also be done by vectorization and would involve a matrix inverse, so solving for $\frac{\partial P_{ij}(x)}{\partial x}$ might not be very straightforward.